# Сохранение инфоблоков в папке local (или в какое-то другое место)

Tags: веб-программирование, битрикс

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Создал типы инфоблоков, инфоблоки и элементы инфоблоков с помощью админки битрикс. Естественно битрикс сохранил эти элементы в папке ядра bitrix. Но сами понимаете, что при переустановке или других операциях, вызывающих перезапись папки bitrix - эти элементы затираются. Каким образом (вернее что и откуда, и куда) можно сохранить типы инфоблоков, инфоблоки и элементы инфоблоков вне папки bitrix (например, в папке local или еще куда-нибудь)? Из какой папки (внутри папки bitrix) можно скопировать и куда (в какую папку внутри local) эти элементы?

Answer (score 1):

> Создал типы инфоблоков, инфоблоки и элементы инфоблоков с помощью админки битрикс. Естественно битрикс сохранил эти элементы в папке ядра bitrix. Но сами понимаете, что при переустановке или других операциях, вызывающих перезапись папки bitrix - эти элементы затираются.

То, что при обновлении ядра Битрикс, его обновляемые стандартные компоненты/модули и т.п. будут затираться - это да, понятно. А Вы про типы ИБ, сами ИБ и элементы понимаете не правильно.

Когда вы создаете Типы ИБ, ИБ и элементы, то это просто очередные записи в базе данных. И при обновлении, никуда они у вас не пропадут. При этом, в папке Битрикс ничего не создается, соответственно и не удалиться/не измениться при обновлении.

Если же Вы имели в виду, что создали страницу в папке Битрикс и там разместили компонент, который выводит вам информацию из ИБ, то во-первых не правильно в этой папке что-либо создать для публичных разделов/страниц, во-вторых эти файлы не сотрутся при обновлении.

Раньше все лежало в папке Битрикс, сейчас же стандартные компоненты/модули/функционал и устанавливаемое из Маркетплейса лежит в папке bitrix, а вот ваши шаблоны, компоненты, модули, дополнения, функционал и другая логика - нужно размещать в папку local. Публичные разделы/страницы размещайте как вам угодно по вашей структуре вне папок bitrix/, local/, upload/